# Syntax for using mr.ripley for benchmarking

Tags: python, benchmarking, plone, zope

I have a Plone 3.3.5 site that I'm migrating to plone.app.blob for BLOB storage.  I'm looking to measure the difference in performance and resource usage by replaying requests to the site, pre-migration and post-migration.

I found that mr.ripley comes with it's own buildout and I used that to install it. That buildout contains a section which creates a script at bin/replay, which is configured by some parameters in the buildout.cfg. The included parameters look like they should work for my instance as I'm running on port 8080 as well.

I copied one of my (smaller) apache logs into the base directory of my mr.ripley buildout and chowned it so that my zope user can read it. Then I try to run it like this:

```
time bin/replay mysite.com_access.log
```

It seems to run (doesn't produce any errors or drop me back into the shell) however I don't see any signs that it's loading up the server. My RAM and CPU usage in `top` still look like the machine is idling.

Many hours later the process does still not seem to have been completed.  I ran it using `screen`, detached and returned several times to the session, but it just seems to be stuck.

Any recommendations as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've performed before and after load testing to test architecture changes. To do this we used JMeter. We took apache logs that represented the typical use we were after. JMeter allows these to be replayed. In addition it will simulate cookies/sessions and browser cache responses to make the request even more realistic. 
Then we built a buildout to deploy jmeter and it's configuration out to several test nodes and let it run.
I know this doesn't answer your direct question but it's an alternative approach.